# Detrended range fluctuation

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to learn how to calculate DFA from wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detrended_fluctuation_analysis

First:

$X_t=\sum_{i=1}^t (x_i-\langle x\rangle)$

Where $X_t$ = cumulative sum, and $\langle x\rangle$ = mean value of time series, and  $t\in {\mathbb  {N}}$

My interpretation using arbitrary numbers $({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})$

$\langle x\rangle$ = 6.5

Deviations = $-5.5,-4.5,-3.5,-2.5,-1.5,-.5,.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,6.5$

Therefore, cumulative sum $X_t$ = $0$

Obviously the sum of deviations from mean will awlays be 0 so I must be missing something here.

Second:

This part confused me even more because it says Next, $X_{t}$ is divided into time windows of length $n$ samples each, and a local least squares straight-line fit (the local trend) is calculated by minimising the squared errors within each time window. Let $Y_{t}$ indicate the resulting piecewise sequence of straight-line fits. Then, the root-mean-square deviation from the trend, the fluctuation, is calculated:

${\displaystyle F(n)={\sqrt {{\frac {1}{N}}\sum _{t=1}^{N}\left(X_{t}-Y_{t}\right)^{2}}}.}$

What defines the length of the time windows and if we are getting multiple least squares regression lines as from my interpretation "$X_t$ is divided into time windows of lengh $n$" then how would one calculate a log-log graph of $F_n$ agains $n$?

Comment: $X_t$ is only zero at $t=N$, where $N$ is the sample size. The point, I imagine, is to study $X_t$ for $1\leq t <N$.

Comment: Yes I think you're right.

Comment: Any other comments on what was mentioned in the post on how to calculate? I have spent weeks trying to find more documentation on examples of how to calculate DFA.

Comment: Well, I can hazard a guess but that is it. Take all the $N$ $X_t$ samples and do least squares on the first $n$, then the next $n$, etc, and you should choose $n$ such that $N=nk$, for some $k$. Hopefully, someone who is actually familiar with DFA can give you a better comment.

Comment: thanks for the comment. If you are taking multiple least squares regression on $n$ and then the next $n$ etc...then you end up with multiple regressions and $F(n)$ is one value. So how would you get one value from multiple regressions?